# Show: $X_n\to X\text{ a.s.}\implies X_n\to X\text{ stochastically }\implies X_n\to X\text{ in distribution}$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ be random variables on one probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Show
> >     $$
> > X_n\to X\text{ a.s.}\implies X_n\to X\text{ stochastically }\implies X_n\to X\text{ in distribution}
> > $$

First of all I give you our definitions of the different meanings of convergence because my experience taught me that there are different words for the same things.

**1)** Convergence a.s.

A sequence $(f_n)$ of numerical measurable functions converges a.s. if there is a null set $N$ so that for $\omega\notin N$ it is $f(\omega)=\lim_n f_n(\omega)$.

**2)** Convergence stochastically

A sequence $(f_n)$ of measurable functions converges locally stochastically to the measurable function $f$ if for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $P(A)<\infty$ and all $\varepsilon >0$ it is $\mu(A\cap\left\{\lvert f_n-f\rvert\right\})\to 0$. If this holds for $\Omega$, too, then it is called stochastically convergent.

**3)** Convergence in distribution

For all bounded continious functions $f$ it is
$$
\lim_n \int f\circ X_n\, dP=\int f\circ X\, dP.
$$

---

Now to what I've tried to make the proof:

First "$\Rightarrow$": If $X_n\to X$ a.s. this implies that $(X_n)$ converges stochastically (locally!) to $X$. But because here it is $P(\Omega)=1<\infty$ the sequence is not only locally stochastically convergent to $X$ but also stochastically.

Second "$\Rightarrow$":

Let $f$ be bounded and continious. I have to show then
$$
\int f(X_n)\ dP\to\int f(X)\, dP.
$$

Do not know how to show that. Can you give me some help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First implication is correct.

For the second one:

$$\left|\int f\circ X_n\, dP - \int f\circ X\, dP\right| \le 
\int | f\circ X_n\ - f\circ X | \,dP \\=
\int_{A_n} | f\circ X_n\ - f\circ X | \,dP + \int_{\Omega - A_n} | f\circ X_n\ - f\circ X | \,dP
$$

Here, let $\epsilon >0$, $\eta$ such as $|x_1 - x_2| < \eta \Rightarrow 
|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| < \frac\epsilon 2$, $A_n = \{ |X_n - X| < \eta\}$ (you can assume $f$ is uniformly continuous, via for instance approximation of $f$ by such functions).

$$\int_{A_n} | f\circ X_n\ - f\circ X | \,dP \le \frac \epsilon 2$$ $$
\int_{\Omega - A_n} | f\circ X_n\ - f\circ X | \,dP \le 2||f|| P(|X_n - X| \ge \eta)$$

Now if $n$ is big enough, $P(|X_n - X| \ge \eta) \le \frac\epsilon{4||f||}$.

Thi gives $$\int f\circ X_n\, dP \to \int f\circ X\, dP$$ as desired.

Comment: Two points that are not totally clear to me yet: (1) Why is $\int_{A_n}\lvert f\circ X_n-f\circ X\rvert\, dP\leqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$? Isn't it $\leqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\cdot P(A_n)$? (2) It's not clear why I can chose wlog f as being uniformly continious.

Comment: (1) it is, but a probability is always $\le 1$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right... very clear.

Comment: For estimating the other integral you used triangle-inequality and the supremum norm $\lVert f\rVert$, right?

Comment: (2) is more complicated, but you can remember that it is enough to prove such a convergence for Lipschitz functions, because of Levy theorem: $X_n\to X$ in law iif  $\forall u\, E\exp(iuX_n) \to E\exp(iuX_n)$. see http://maikolsolis.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/characteristic-functions-levys-continuity-theorem/

Comment: @math12 : indeed.